# Leaflet Binding Pop-ups To Markers

Tags: map, trailhead, popup

I did the trailhead project for the Geolocation of Accounts. Now to improve this feature I tried to add pop-ups to the markers and I have searched already several hours for a solution. Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I am using the exact correct code as the solutions that I found. Maybe someone on here has experience with this 'error'.

I do see all the markers, but when I click on them nothing happens. And according to the Leaflet documentation, you don't have to add extra events for opening the pop-ups.

Code:

```
for (var i=0; i<accounts.length; i++) {
            var account = accounts[i];
            var latLng = [account.BillingLatitude, account.BillingLongitude];
            L.marker([account.BillingLatitude, account.BillingLongitude])
            .addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.");
        }
```

Comment: Changing `<br>` to `<br/>` does anything?

Comment: I was hoping this would help, but nope that was not a problem.

Comment: Did you try adding `.openPopup()` method at end after bindPopup? as mentioned in example [here](http://leafletjs.com/index.html). [Quick start guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) has more details.

Comment: with the 'openPopup()' one Popup will open when the map is loaded. But as you can see in my code in the original question,  there are several markers being created in a loop.

Comment: Ah you are right, Do you see any error in Chrome dev console?

Comment: Nope no errors.. That's the frustration of this all..